# Changes to my model/viewModel are not updating my view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am creating a sample app in SwiftUI and changes to one of my model's properties are not causing the view to update which it should. I have already tested that the network call is working as expected and the model is being updated with the new text but it isn't causing the view to be rebuilt and show the new text. I am passing my viewModel through the App object. The text view always shows "initial value" so What might be happening?

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  
 @Published var model = Model()
  
  var factText: String {
    return model.factText
    
  }
  
  func getNewFact() {
    model.networkCall()
  }
  
  
}

struct ContentView: View {
  
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button("New Fact") {
        viewModel.getNewFact()
        //              print(viewModel.model.factText)
      }
      Text(viewModel.model.factText)
    }
    .padding()
  }
}
class Model {
  
  var factText = "initial value"
  
  func networkCall() {
    
    let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["X-Api-Key": Constants.apiKey]
    
    AF.request(Constants.url, headers: headers)
      .responseDecodable(of: [Response].self) {response in
        
        self.factText = response.value![0].fact

      }

  }
 
}


@main
struct FunFactsWatchApp_Watch_AppApp: App {
    var game = ViewModel()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
          ContentView(viewModel: game)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `View` struct is the view model already you don't need an object. Use `.task` and `.task(id:)` in `body` for async networking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference types like classes cannot be `@Publish`ed because the instance (pointer) doesn't change when a property is modified (actually they can but this is not needed and beyond the question).

`Model` must be a struct

```
struct Model {
    var factText: String // can even be `let`
}
```

the network call must be in the view model

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var model = Model(factText: "")
    
    func networkCall() {
        
        let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["X-Api-Key": Constants.apiKey]
        
        AF.request(Constants.url, headers: headers)
            .responseDecodable(of: [Response].self) {response in
                
                self.model = Model(factText: response.value![0].fact)
            }
    }
}
```

and you have to create and initialize a `@StateObject` in `ContentView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("New Fact") {
                viewModel.networkCall()
            }
            Text(viewModel.model.factText)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```